# redirect is not working for custom middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

I am using Laravel project version 5.8.

I have used two middleware `Admin` and `Author`.

I have created both `AdminMiddleware` and `AuthorMiddlware`.

I registered both in `Kernel.php`. I changed `RedirectIfAuthenticated`, `loginController` for custom redirect. I have created different route groups.

For admin middleware it will redirect `admin.dashboard` and for author middleware it will redirect to `author.dashboard`.

After then, it is redirecting to the `/home` route as in the default laravel logged in users. ***I want to redirect admin to admin.dashboard and author to author.dashboard after login***.Custom redirect is not working. I viewed my project several times but unable to find the issue.

***loginController.php***

```
// protected $redirectTo = '/home';
public function __construct(){
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1) {
        return redirect()->route('author.dashboard');
    } else if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==2) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }else {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

***RedirectIfAuthenticated.php***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1) {
        return redirect()->route('author.dashboard');
    }else if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==2) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');;
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

***AuthorMiddleware***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('/login');
    }
}
```

***AdminMiddleware***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==2){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('/login');
    }
}
```

***Web.php***

```
Route::group(['as'=>'author.','prefix'=>'author','namespace'=>'Author','middleware' => 'author'], function () {
Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});

Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

***Author/DashobardController***

```
public function index()
{
    return view('author.dashboard');
}
```

***Admin/DashobardController***

```
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.dashboard');
}
```

***I am new in Laravel. Faced this problem first time and unable to find issues please help.***

Comment: Do you redirect to `/home` after login?

Comment: I want to redirect admin to `admin.dashboard` and author to `author.dashboard` after login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the following lines into your `LoginController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1) {
        return redirect()->route('author.dashboard');
    } else if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==2) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
//protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Change**

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1) {
        return '/author/dashboard';
    }else if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id==2) {
        return 'admin/dashboard';
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Or**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){
    if (Auth::user()->role->id==1) {
        return '/author/dashboard';
    }else if (Auth::user()->role->id==2) {
        return 'admin/dashboard';
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Logincontoller.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==1) {
        return 'author/dashboard';
    } else if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id==2) {
        return 'admin/dashboard';
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
//protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
}
```

Comment: Same Change in also `logincontroller.php`

Comment: Still it's redirecting to the `/home` route.

Comment: Have you change in login controller??

Comment: `/author/dashboard` is working fine but not redirect to this after login. I checked your code. I changed both the loginController and redirectiifautheticate.

Comment: Is there any other file need to change? any other location?